# I am dynamically adding div to the DOM via JS and using appendChild and later on removeChild. But when appending for the 2nd time it wont work

Tags: javascript, appendchild, removechild

In the code below, `create()` works fine the first time but in the second time something goes wrong at `boxWrapper.appendChild(box);`. seems like the removeChild messes up the parent box-wrapper properties.

```
function pixels() {
    const value = document.querySelector("#value")
    const input = document.querySelector("#pixels")

    value.textContent = input.value

    input.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        value.textContent = event.target.value
    })

    return input.value;
}

function create() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('box'); // get all elements

    let z = elements.length;

    let a = pixels();
    let b = a * a;
    let c = (1 / a) * 100;

    if (z == 0) {

        for (i = 1; i < (b + 1); i++) {
            var boxWrapper = document.getElementById("box-wrapper");

            var box = document.createElement("div");

            box.innerHTML = '1';
            box.style.backgroundColor = "light green";

            var input_percen = c + "%";

            box.style.width = input_percen;
            box.style.height = input_percen;

            box.classList.add("box");

            box.addEventListener('mouseover', function onMouseover(event) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            });

            boxWrapper.appendChild(box);   
        }
    } else {
        reset();
    }

}

function reset() {
    while (div = document.getElementById("box-wrapper")) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

    }
    create();
}
```

I am expecting to clear box-wrapper and being able to appendChilds multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're removing the div you're trying to empty itself:

```
function reset() {
    while (div = document.getElementById("box-wrapper")) {
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

    }
    create();
}
```

You're selecting the `parentNode` from `#box-wrapper` and then you remove the `#box-wrapper` div from the childs.

Instead of removing the `div` itself, try setting the `innerHTML` to empty:

```
function reset() {
    div = document.getElementById("box-wrapper");
    div.innerHTML = '';
    
    create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the `div#box-wrapper` from the DOM by doing :

```
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
```

To remove all children from this div, you could use [`replaceChildren()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) :

```
document.getElementById("box-wrapper").replaceChildren();
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much.
i have gone with:

`function reset() {

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('box'); // get all elements
console.log(elements.length);
let q = elements.length;
 for(let i = 0; i < q; i++){
 elements[0].remove();
 }`
```

Thanks!!